# How to decide how much memory to allocate per core for MPI app GENE?

Tags: memory, smp

This is required information for some MPI using app that I am working with...

From its Makefile *template*:

```
#insert memory per core and uncomment the following line
#PREPROC= -D'MB_PER_CORE=750'
```

Note that said scientific app runs also on NUMA machines, like Cray, where each core has its own memory.  I am asking here what to put in above line on ***Linux*** on e.g. 12GB machine with 16 cores.

Comment: I don't understand the question. On most architectures, the RAM is shared between all cores. Processes aren't associated with particular cores either. What information are you after?

Comment: I have added fragment of Makefile template of said app that talks about "**memory per core**".  Your guess is as good as mine in what it mean; I think it might be total memory / number of cores (CPUs).

Comment: It depends on what the program does with that parameter.  Total memory / number of cores would be a good starting point, but if it actually tries to allocate that much memory per core, you'd probably want to use a smaller value.  On the other hand, maybe that parameter is only for use on NUMA machines.  You haven't given us enough information for a definitive answer.

Comment: Is this scientific app open source?  If so, what is its homepage?

Comment: Voting to close as there is not enough information provided here.

Comment: @PhilipDurbin: It's GENE (Gyrokinetic Electromagnetic Numerical Experiment): http://www.ipp.mpg.de/~fsj/gene/